# How to change the primary color in Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

In my variables.scss file I have my primary color as brown. I have 2 theme file:

theme.green.scss
theme.yellow.scss

If i want to make green and yellow as primary colors for my themes, how can I do that ? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

this deppends on what version of ionic you are using if version 3 and 4 navigate to src/theme/variables.scss their you can change the color.

Answer (score 1):

You can change or add new color using this code :

First go to `src/global.scss`

```
:root {
    --ion-color-gold: #ffd700;
    --ion-color-gold-rgb: 255, 215, 0;
    --ion-color-gold-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-gold-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --ion-color-gold-shade: #e0bd00;
    --ion-color-gold-tint: #ffdb1a;
}
.ion-color-gold {
    --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-gold) !important;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-gold-rgb) !important;
    --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-gold-contrast) !important;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-gold-contrast-rgb) !important;
    --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-gold-shade) !important;
    --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-gold-tint) !important;
}
```

So right now you have a new color called `gold` when you can use it like that  :

```
<ion-button color="gold">We now have a gold button :)</ion-button>
```

> if you want to change `primary` color just change `gold` in
> `--ion-color-gold: #ffd700;` each line to `primary` in this way you can
> change it .

[Reference](https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-how-to-add-more-colors-and-use-them-as-color-in-buttons-and-more-7175ab4ae4e7)